# String... <varname> whats does String... mean

Tags: java

Im trying to figure out some java code.
I came across something I have not seen before in a method header

```
private static object [] methodName(NodeList nodes, String... Names)
```

Whats is the operator `...`?

Thanks and sorry did some searches could not find it elsewhere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) declaration.

It's saying that you can call that method with 0 or more String arguments as the final arguments. Instead of:

```
write(new String[]{"A","B","C"});
```

you can use

```
write("A", "B", "C");
```

So each string is a different argument. You can then iterate through them e.g.

```
public void write(String... records) {
   for (String record: records)
      System.out.println(record);
}
```

More examples [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3323661).

Comment: how does this differ from passing an array of Strings. Is it that a array of Strings cannot call the method with 0 Strings?

Comment: Thanks excuse my Qs Im a bit of a newbie

Comment: No problem. That's what we're all here for!

Answer (score 2):

The `...` denotes "varargs", i.e. you can provide an arbitrary number of `String` arguments.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html.